On GPA and Applying for PhD
I am an undergraduate studying mathematics interested in pursuing research in this field. I am interested in differential geometry and have tried several courses involving geometry/analysis. However, I have B+ grades for these courses, which I believe is because I couldn't react to exams as quickly as many others in the same class. I can clearly explain my understanding to others and solve many difficult questions under untimed conditions. Will these B+ grades impact my application if I want to pursue a math PhD degree in a geometry-related field?
